# deciding a template type depending on a another template type

Tags: c++, templates

Can I assign template type say T a type, depending on another template type say U
something like this inside a function.

```
typename <class T, class U>
func(U var)
{
...

if(U == int) //this can be replaced with std::is_same<U, int>
{
    T = flaot; //instead int/float i have my own data types

}
...
}
```

Is this possible.. if so how is it done

Comment: You probably rather want to use SFINAE  and template specialization to do this.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the argument given or do you want `T` to be determined automatically / by default in a certain way? Please give a use case example.

Comment: I want T to be determined depending on the type U... If U is int then T will be userType1 or if U is char then T will be userType2

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it is what you want, but you might try this:

```
template <typename T>
class Selector; // implement this one as well, if you want to have a default...

template <> class Selector<int> { public: using Type = ClassX; };
template <> class Selector<double> { public: using Type = ClassY; };

template<typename U>
void func(U var)
{
    using T = typename Selector<U>::Type;
};
```

Variant:

```
template<typename U, typename T = typename Selector<U>::Type>
void func(U var) { }
```

This would allow to replace the selected type, if need be:

```
func(12);              // uses default: ClassX
func<int, ClassZ>(10); // replace ClassX with ClassZ
```

Comment: I found the answer in your answer... I can use "using type = is_same<T, int>::value? usertype1 : usertype2;"

Comment: @harsha That shouldn't work. You cannot use the ternary operator with the operands being types.

Comment: @harsha There's [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional), though... Do I see this right, it's *only* for int that you need another type, all others (long, double, unsigned int, classes, ...) use the same?